# PHP array_combine with $_GET does not return all array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form which submits a **status** and a **id** as arrays to an update.php. Below is the submitting form input and the sent URL

```
<? echo"<input type='hidden' name='status[]' value='$status' />"; ?>
<? echo"<input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='$id' />"; ?>

update_pnr.php?status%5B%5D=0&id%5B%5D=4&status%5B%5D=0&id%5B%5D=5
```

The PHP which should update the incoming information is:

```
$newarr = array_combine($_GET['status'],$_GET['id']);
foreach($newarr as $index => $value){
    echo 'index: ' . $index . 'Value: ' . $value . '<br>';
}
```

I was expecting:

```
0 Value: 4
0 Value: 5
```

But the first line is ignored, I receive only the last line. Why is that ?

Comment: You can use post method instead of get method

Comment: when both status are == 0 then they can only one key that is 0. $arr[0] = 1; $arr[0] = 2; echo $arr[0]; //2

Comment: var_dump you $_GET first

Comment: @Ramki how using `POST` instead of `GET` will make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround:

```
foreach($_GET['status'] as $key => $val)
   echo $val . 'Value: ' . $_GET['id'][$key];
```

Comment: Your answer does not explain what was OP problem in array combine :)

Comment: look at the comments at the question.

Answer (score 2):

As far doc `array_combine`

*Creates an array by using the values from the keys array as keys and the values from the values array as the corresponding values.*

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

First parameter array's value  is use as keys and second parameter array's value use as values

```
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)
```

**Your scenario is:**

Your array `$_GET['status']`:

```
Array(
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )
```

array `$_GET['id']`:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
        )
```

After combine it becomes:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
)
```

Because array status has same value twice which are the keys of combined array. Since key is unique it overwrite with the last value:

`$newarr[0] => 4` and then   `$newarr[0] => 5`

`$newarr[0] => 4` overwrite by

```
$newarr[0] => 5
```

and   `$newarr` has only one key and value.

[Live analysis](https://eval.in/382548)

Comment: OP asked for reason why it is happening. OP did not asked for solution @v.eigler

Comment: I wrote the reason in the comment but what helps is the solution.